# Constructing PEPS representation of an arbitrary quantum state

Tags: condensed-matter, lattice-model, spin-models, tensor-network

Given a quantum state we can  construct its MPS (Matrix Product State) representation by doing a series of singular value decompositions. Given the freedom to choose arbitrary bond dimensions the MPS representation is powerful enough to represent any quantum state.

I have read that PEPS (Projected Entangled-Pair State) is seen as a natural extension of MPS to general graphs. Then given a quantum state and some graph is there an algorithm that constructs a PEPS equal to that state on that graph ? Any reference to such an algorithm would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful, both to people answering your question and people subsequently trying to learn from it, if you define what your acronyms mean

Answer (score 1):

You can always embed an MPS into the 2D graph -- possibly by using edges twice -- and then use the same method as for MPS.  Alternatively, you can e.g. block the graph into slices such as to obtain a 1D structure and then first to the MPS decomposition and subsequently decompose the slices.